# Remove Default Action validation

Tags: struts2, struts-validation

I am using Struts validation by extending action to ActionSupport.

When I try to put special character on the UI, then default actionErrors are adding up in the collections like **Illegal characters were detected in the input, please remove them and try again.**

Then I need to remove that default validation coming up on UI. I have no idea to deal with it.

My code is like this:

```java
void validate(){  
    if (locationBean.getReasonTypeId() == 0)  
   {  
     addActionError("Error in reason");  
    }  
      if (ValidationHelper.checkRequiredField(locationBean.getName()))  
    {  
      addActionError("Error in Location name");  
    }  
}
```

My validation action class is like this:

```java
public class ValidationErrorJSONAction extends ActionSupport  
{  
  private JSONObject jsonObject;  

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  
  public String execute() throws Exception  
  {    
    jsonObject = new JSONObject();  
    jsonObject.put("actionErrors", new JSONArray(getActionErrors()));  
    jsonObject.put("fieldErrors",new JSONObject(getFieldErrors()));  
    TokenHelperJSON.appendToken(jsonObject);  

    return SUCCESS;  
  }
```

Hope it will help you to understand the problem.

Comment: Do you use a config files, if so post it here.

Comment: You don't need to shutdown the validation, but to setup a correct Encoding through your application. Refer to the great explanation by BalusC here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177914/passing-turkish-char-from-form-to-java-class-with-struts2